# Jenkins Fan-In Plug-in Job DSL Configure Block

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

The [Jenkins Fan-In Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/job-fan-in/) is not natively supported by the Jenkins Job DSL Plugin.

I need a Job DSL Configure Block to be able to add a Fan-In Plugin to my existing Job DSL groovy scripts.

Comment: Too add such a feature, you should Open a [JIRA feature ticket](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-52296?jql=%20component%3D21443) and hope the plugin owner still supports it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  We're here to help people learn and solve problems, and that sometimes means suggesting an alternative implementation.

There are a couple of things you can do to help get a better answer:

1. Describe what you want to achieve.  It's possible the community may be able to suggest a solution that doesn't rely on merging these two libraries.  If it's _mandatory_ to use the Fan In plugin, make that clear.

2. Share the relevant part of your DSL implementation or Groovy scripts to help give us some context.

It's also helpful to read (How to ask a good question)[https://